# Какая допущена ошибка в поиске?

Tags: c++

В место того чтобы выдавать порядковый номер найденного слова, выдает левое число, абсолютно неверное.

```
using namespace std;  
int main()  
{
ifstream file("text.txt");  
string s;  
char c, find;  
int pos=0,i=0,rows_count=0; 
     while (!file.eof())
{  // прочитали его и заполнили им строку
    file.get(c);
    s.push_back(c);
}   {   
  for(i=0; i<s.size(); ++i)
      (s[i++]);
      rows_count = i;  
cout << "Words get "<< rows_count << endl;

file.close(); // обязательно закрыли

cout << "enter a world for find: ";
cin >> find;   { 
for(i=0; i<s.size(); ++i)  // дальше поиск не корректный
if(s[i] == find) 
{
cout << "Finded in " << i << " simvol position" << endl;
goto end;
}  }end:;
cout << "Word not finded " << endl;
system("pause");
return 0;}}
```

Comment: что вы подразоумеваете под словом индекс?

Comment: Порядковый номер слова.

Comment: Думаю, у Вас ошибка в том, что `c` и `find` должны быть типа `string` (чтобы хранить целое *слово*, а не один *символ*). Тогда `s` нужно объявить как `vector<string> s`.

Тогда можно читать файл по словам,  используя `file >> c`.

--

Кстати, в дальнейшем, будьте так любезны, пишите формулировку задачи (что на входе и что требуется с ним сделать), а не заставляйте нас восстанавливать  ее по коду с ошибками.

--

И что бы на Вас меньше ругались, замените `goto` на `break` (а как сделать корректный (только если действительно требуется) вывод сообщения `"Word not found" все же придумайте сами).

Comment: Я бы поставил двойку за одно только оформление исходников. Какая-то каша. Объявление переменных в начале программы, а не там, где они нужны - атавизмы-паскализмы. Смысл цикла for с телом (s[i++]); я вообще понять не могу. Что он делает, по-вашему? Настораживает, что строка rows_count = i; с отступом. Вы осознаете, что она вне цикла?

Comment: @VadimTukaev, очевидно же, тайный смысл:

    for(i=0; i<s.size(); ++i)
      (s[i++]);
    rows_count = i; 

именно в том, чтобы "any kind soul", ответила на животрепещущий (но скромно припрятанный) вопрос, почему:

    cout << "Words get "<< rows_count << endl;

*выдает левое число, абсолютно неверное*?

Человек мучается, а Вы сразу двойки за оформление...

Comment: 

@Sergos сформулируйте свой вопрос конкретней в развернутом виде. не скупитесь на лишние слова. обычно залог успеха состоит в правильной постановки задачи. мне непонятно что такое порядковый номер слова. то ли это поиск позиции номера с которого начинается искомое слово. то ли нужно выводить номер начала позиции повторяющегося слова найденого в n-ый раз

Comment: Хорошо. Спасибо всем за помощь.